# How to execute same JDBC query with different where conditions

Tags: jdbc

I have a java method like

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeById(Long id){
    final String query = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID=?";
    preparedStatement.setLong(1,id);

   // from the result set prepare employee object
   // close result set
   // close prepared stmt
   // close connection.
}
```

Now how do i change the method, so that my where clause can be 'where name=?' or 'where dept=?' or some other criteria.

i.e.
1. I need not to parse resultset to employee obj as i am using simple jdbc.
2. no need of writing same boiler plate code (i.e. closing result set, preparedstmt, conn)

I want to use simple JDBC.
Do I need to write different methods for this or is there any other way. 
Please help me in solving this.

Comment: You could pass those params in your method arguments and reference them in your query.  Not glamorous but it'd work if you're just changing one scope.

Comment: I have 6 different kind of conditions, then my arg list will become more lengthy & ugly.

Comment: They obviously aren't the same query as they have different conditions; I'd suggest to treat them as such.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class which contains these parameters. Pass the instance of the class rather than lengthy parameters.
i.e.

```
Class xyz = new Class();
```

xyz.TableName = "Whatever";
xyz. employeeID = 12345;

then execute:
getEmployeeByID(xyz);